# Bootstrap 3 Change display:block to another value

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

When I am looking at a checkbox based on Bootstrap 3 class "checkbox" in IE Development Tools the display is set to block, as:

```
display:block;
```

When I uncheck the box in front of the display:block it now has cross-over line.  Now the checkbox looks exactly how I want.  So I need to specify in the inline style the value for display that is equal to the crossed over display:block being unchecked. I tried different values for display in the inline style but nothing works.  What do you suggest I set as the value for display in the inline style?

Here is the segment of the code:

```
<div class="checkbox" style="min-height:20px;padding-top:3px">
       <asp:CheckBox ID="chkCloseWo" runat="server" CssClass="checkbox" />
</div>
```

Here is the HTML code:

```
<div class="checkbox" style="min-height:20px;padding-top:3px;display:inherit">
    <span class="checkbox"><input id="MainContent_chkCloseWo" type="checkbox" name="ctl00    $MainContent$chkCloseWo" /></span>
 </div>
```

Comment: Sorry I'm a little confused, could you add screenshots of what you're trying to achieve or more code?

Comment: @ShalomAptekar Hard to get a screen shot (I simply don't know how to attach an image in Stackoverflow). But let me describe. By default Bootstrap 3 show the check box a little down and to the right. When I uncheck it in Dev Tools the checkbox moves to the left and up a little.

Comment: @BillyMoat  the "static" is not an option in the pull-down list of choices for display.

Comment: My bad, try 'inline', that's the default value afaik.

Comment: @BillyMoat Not a problem. Inline does move the checkbox to the left (which is one of the desired results). But at the same time the checkbox is not way too down; as if the height of the checkbox box is too high.  Thank you.

Comment: Here's a Bootstrap 3 fiddle. Put your code snippet in it so we can see what's happening. http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/MMxMn/

Comment: @Isherwood  I tried to put my code into the fiddle but nothing shows. So I edited my initial post and added the code. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, don't put ASP code in a fiddle. Show us the HTML, which is what the CSS acts on.

Comment: @Isherwood  Isn't the code I added to my initial post the HTML code? Sorry if I am not seeing something obvious.

Comment: `<asp>` is not an HTML tag. It's server-side syntax that gets converted to HTML by your app. Look at the page code.

Comment: @Isherwood  I see now. Let me correct myself.

Comment: I was able to achieve almost what I wanted by doing the following:
I changed the default padding-left: 20px to padding-left: 10px
And made padding-top:0px

If I could specify negative padding-top (to move the checkbox 2px up) it would be exactly what the unchecking display:block was doing.  

But this is probably good enough.

Thank you all.